# Multiple dragging in same fields will change previous data to default

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

When I drag and drop a file into content if I add some text and then another file drag and drop then previous file's all data changes to default

```
      <td align="right">

          <!-- <div id="sortable"></div>-->
<h2  class="heading_play">My Playlist</h2>
<ol class="droppable">
 <li>
 <div class="drop1" id="buttons2" class="buttons2">

                </div>
 </div>

 <li>
</ol>
            <!--<div class="pro_iframe"><iframe src="index_iframe.html" width="100%" height="100%" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></div></iframe>-->
            </td>
```

when i drag and drop a file into content if i add some text and then another file drag and drop then previous file's all data changes to default

```
        function checkField(val){

var data=val;
alert(data);
   }

  //<!--

   function threeblocks(id){
document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
       }

        var start=1;
 function hideblocks(id){
  document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
  //alert('hi');
 start++;
 }

  //-->

//<![CDATA[ 
   $(window).load(function(){
$(".draggable li").draggable({
    appendTo: 'body',
    helper: 'clone',
    connectToSortable: '.sortable',
});


$(".droppable").droppable({
    drop: function(event,ui) {


        if(ui.draggable.attr("class") =="letmego ui-draggable"){
            write = document.getElementById('buttons2');
            write.innerHTML = write.innerHTML +"<div class=\"sortable\" id=\"outhide"+ start+"\"><div class=\"drag_icon_out\" ><div class=\"list_box\"><h2><input name=\"\" id=\"star1"+ start+"\" type=\"text\" value=\"Ttttttttttttttttt\" class=\"list_box_input\" onchange=\"return checkField(this.value);\"><br /></div></div></div>";
             var star=document.getElementById('star1'+ start).value;



        }else if(ui.draggable.attr("class") =="letmego2 ui-draggable"){
            write = document.getElementById('buttons2');
            write.innerHTML = write.innerHTML +"<div class=\"sortable\" id=\"outhide2"+ start+"\"><div class=\"drag_icon_out\"><div class=\"list_box\"><div class=\"cam_out2\"><span><img src=\"images/drag_icon2.png\" alt=\"\"></span></div><h2><input name=\"\" id=\"star2"+ start+"\" type=\"text\" id=\"star2\" value=\"Title \" class=\"list_box_input\" onchange=\"return checkField(this.value);\"><br /><input name=\"\" type=\"text\" value=\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\" class=\"list_box_input2\"></h2><div class=\"list_box_img2\"><h2>Add Content<br><span>Click the Edit button below.</span</h2></div><div class=\"list_box_icon2\"><div class=\"list_box_inn\"><a class=\"fancybox\" href=\"images/lighboxt_img2.jpg\" data-fancybox-group=\"gallery\" title=\"Rules to Solve Proportions2\"><div class=\"list_box_2\"><img src=\"images/box_icon1.png\" alt=\"\"></div></a><a href=\"javascript:;\" onClick=\"hideblocks('outhide2" + start+ "')\"><div class=\"delete_box_3\"><img src=\"images/delete_icon.png\" alt=\"\"></div></a><div class=\"list_box_3\"><div class=\"box_message\">2</div><img src=\"images/box_icon2.png\" alt=\"\"></div><div class=\"list_box_4\"><div class=\"box_message\">1</div><img src=\"images/box_icon3.png\" alt=\"\"></div><div class=\"list_box_5\"><img src=\"images/box_icon4.png\" alt=\"\"></div></div></div></div></div></div>";
        var star=document.getElementById('star2'+ start).value;

        }else if(ui.draggable.attr("class") =="letmego3 ui-draggable"){
            write = document.getElementById('buttons2');
            write.innerHTML = write.innerHTML +"<div class=\"sortable\" id=\"outhide3"+ start+"\"><div class=\"drag_icon_out\"><div class=\"list_box\" ><div class=\"cam_out23\"><span><img src=\"images/drag_icon32.png\" alt=\"\"></span></div><h2><input name=\"\" id=\"star3"+ start+"\" type=\"text\" id=\"star3\" value=\"goes here\" class=\"list_box_input\" onchange=\"return checkField(this.value);\"><br /><input name=\"\" type=\"text\" value=\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\" class=\"list_box_input2\"></h2><div class=\"list_box_img3\"><h2>Add Content<br><span>Click the Edit button below.</span</h2></div><div class=\"list_box_icon2\"><div class=\"list_box_inn\"><a class=\"fancybox\" href=\"images/lighboxt_img3.jpg\" data-fancybox-group=\"gallery\" title=\"Rules to Solve Proportions3\"><div class=\"list_box_2\"><img src=\"images/box_icon1.png\" alt=\"\"></div></a><a href=\"javascript:;\" onClick=\"hideblocks('outhide3" + start+ "')\"><div class=\"delete_box_3\"><img src=\"images/delete_icon.png\" alt=\"\"></div></a><div class=\"list_box_3\"><div class=\"box_message\">2</div><img src=\"images/box_icon2.png\" alt=\"\"></div><div class=\"list_box_4\"><div class=\"box_message\">1</div><img src=\"images/box_icon3.png\" alt=\"\"></div><div class=\"list_box_5\"><img src=\"images/box_icon4.png\" alt=\"\"></div></div></div></div></div></div>";

        var star=document.getElementById('star3'+ start).value;

        }else if(ui.draggable.attr("class") =="letmego4 ui-draggable"){
            write = document.getElementById('buttons2');
            write.innerHTML = write.innerHTML +"<div class=\"sortable\" id=\"outhide4"+ start+"\"><div class=\"drag_icon_out\"><div class=\"list_box\" ><div class=\"cam_out3\"><span><img src=\"images/drag_icon4.png\" alt=\"\"></span></div><h2><input name=\"\"  id=\"star4"+ start+"\" type=\"text\" id=\"star4\" value=\"Title goes \" class=\"list_box_input\" onchange=\"return checkField(this.value);\"><br /><input name=\"\" type=\"text\" value=\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\" class=\"list_box_input2\"></h2><div class=\"list_box_img4\"><h2>Add Content<br><span>Click the Edit button below.</span</h2></div><div class=\"list_box_icon2\"><div class=\"list_box_inn\"><a class=\"fancybox\" href=\"images/lighboxt_img4.jpg\" data-fancybox-group=\"gallery\" title=\"Rules to Solve Proportions4\"><div class=\"list_box_2\"><img src=\"images/box_icon1.png\" alt=\"\"></div></a><a href=\"javascript:;\" onClick=\"hideblocks('outhide4" + start+ "')\"><div class=\"delete_box_3\"><img src=\"images/delete_icon.png\" alt=\"\"></div></a><div class=\"list_box_3\"><div class=\"box_message\">2</div><img src=\"images/box_icon2.png\" alt=\"\"></div><div class=\"list_box_4\"><div class=\"box_message\">1</div><img src=\"images/box_icon3.png\" alt=\"\"></div><div class=\"list_box_5\"><img src=\"images/box_icon4.png\" alt=\"\"></div></div></div></div></div></div>";

        var star=document.getElementById('star4'+ start).value;


        }else if(ui.draggable.attr("class") =="letmego5 ui-draggable"){
            write = document.getElementById('buttons2');
            write.innerHTML = write.innerHTML +"<div class=\"sortable\" id=\"outhide5"+ start+"\"><div class=\"drag_icon_out\"><div class=\"list_box\" ><div class=\"cam_out4\"><span><img src=\"images/drag_icon5.png\" alt=\"\"></span></div><h2><input name=\"\" id=\"star5"+ start+"\" type=\"text\" id=\"star5\" value=\"Tis here\" class=\"list_box_input\" onchange=\"return checkField(this.value);\"><br /><input name=\"\" type=\"text\" value=\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\" class=\"list_box_input2\"></h2><div class=\"list_box_img5\"><h2>Add Content<br><span>Click the Edit button below.</span</h2></div><div class=\"list_box_icon2\"><div class=\"list_box_inn\"><a class=\"fancybox\" href=\"images/lighboxt_img5.jpg\" data-fancybox-group=\"gallery\" title=\"Rules to Solve Proportions\"><div class=\"list_box_2\"><img src=\"images/box_icon1.png\" alt=\"\"></div></a><a href=\"javascript:;\" onClick=\"hideblocks('outhide5" + start+ "')\"><div class=\"delete_box_3\"><img src=\"images/delete_icon.png\" alt=\"\"></div></a><div class=\"list_box_3\"><div class=\"box_message\">2</div><img src=\"images/box_icon2.png\" alt=\"\"></div><div class=\"list_box_4\"><div class=\"box_message\">1</div><img src=\"images/box_icon3.png\" alt=\"\"></div><div class=\"list_box_5\"><img src=\"images/box_icon4.png\" alt=\"\"></div></div></div></div></div></div>";
        var star=document.getElementById('star5'+ start).value;

        }
        else if(ui.draggable.attr("class") =="letmego6 ui-draggable"){
            write = document.getElementById('buttons2');
            write.innerHTML = write.innerHTML +"<div class=\"sortable\" id=\"outhide6"+ start+"\"><div class=\"drag_icon_out\"><div class=\"list_box\" ><div class=\"cam_out5\"><span><img src=\"images/drag_icon62.png\" alt=\"\"></span></div><h2><input name=\"\"  id=\"star6"+ start+"\" type=\"text\" id=\"star6\" value=\"Titleere\" class=\"list_box_input\" onchange=\"return checkField(this.value);\"><br /><input name=\"\" type=\"text\" value=\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\" class=\"list_box_input2\"></h2><div class=\"list_box_img6\"><h2>Add Content<br><span>Click the Edit button below.</span</h2></div><div class=\"list_box_icon2\"><div class=\"list_box_inn\"><a class=\"fancybox\" href=\"images/lighboxt_img6.jpg\" data-fancybox-group=\"gallery\" title=\"Rules to Solve Proportions5\"><div class=\"list_box_2\"><img src=\"images/box_icon1.png\" alt=\"\"></div></a><a href=\"javascript:;\" onClick=\"hideblocks('outhide6" + start+ "')\"><div class=\"delete_box_3\"><img src=\"images/delete_icon.png\" alt=\"\"></div></a><div class=\"list_box_3\"><div class=\"box_message\">2</div><img src=\"images/box_icon2.png\" alt=\"\"></div><div class=\"list_box_4\"><div class=\"box_message\">1</div><img src=\"images/box_icon3.png\" alt=\"\"></div><div class=\"list_box_5\"><img src=\"images/box_icon4.png\" alt=\"\"></div></div></div></div></div></div>";
        var star=document.getElementById('star6'+ start).value;

        }
        else if(ui.draggable.attr("class") =="letmego7 ui-draggable"){
            write = document.getElementById('buttons2');
            write.innerHTML = write.innerHTML +"<div class=\"sortable\" id=\"outhide7"+ start+"\"><div class=\"drag_icon_out\"><div class=\"list_box\"><div class=\"cam_out6\"><span><img src=\"images/drag_icon7.png\" alt=\"\"></span></div><h2><input name=\"\" id=\"star7"+ start+"\" type=\"text\" id=\"star7\" value=\"Tere\" class=\"list_box_input\" onchange=\"return checkField(this.value);\"><br /><input name=\"\" type=\"text\" value=\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\" class=\"list_box_input2\"></h2><div class=\"list_box_img7\"><h2>Add Content<br><span>Click the Edit button below.</span</h2></div><div class=\"list_box_icon2\"><div class=\"list_box_inn\"><a class=\"fancybox\" href=\"images/lighboxt_img7.jpg\" data-fancybox-group=\"gallery\" title=\"Rules to Solve Proportions6\"><div class=\"list_box_2\"><img src=\"images/box_icon1.png\" alt=\"\"></div></a><a href=\"javascript:;\" onClick=\"hideblocks('outhide7" + start+ "')\"><div class=\"delete_box_3\"><img src=\"images/delete_icon.png\" alt=\"\"></div></a><div class=\"list_box_3\"><div class=\"box_message\">2</div><img src=\"images/box_icon2.png\" alt=\"\"></div><div class=\"list_box_4\"><div class=\"box_message\">1</div><img src=\"images/box_icon3.png\" alt=\"\"></div><div class=\"list_box_5\"><img src=\"images/box_icon4.png\" alt=\"\"></div></div></div></div></div></div>";
        var star=document.getElementById('star7'+ start).value;
                alert(star);
        }
        else if(ui.draggable.attr("class") =="letmego8 ui-draggable"){
            write = document.getElementById('buttons2');
            write.innerHTML = write.innerHTML +"<div class=\"sortable\" id=\"outhide8"+ start+"\"><div class=\"drag_icon_out\"><div class=\"list_box\"><div class=\"cam_out7\"><span><img src=\"images/drag_icon8.png\" alt=\"\"></span></div><h2><input name=\"\" id=\"star8"+ start+"\" type=\"text\" id=\"star8\" value=\"leoes here\" class=\"list_box_input\" onchange=\"return checkField(this.value);\"><br /><input name=\"\" type=\"text\" value=\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\" class=\"list_box_input2\"></h2><div class=\"list_box_img8\"><h2>Add Content<br><span>Click the Edit button below.</span</h2></div><div class=\"list_box_icon2\"><div class=\"list_box_inn\"><a class=\"fancybox\" href=\"images/lighboxt_img8.jpg\" data-fancybox-group=\"gallery\" title=\"Rules to Solve Proportions7\"><div class=\"list_box_2\"><img src=\"images/box_icon1.png\" alt=\"\"></div></a><a href=\"javascript:;\" onClick=\"hideblocks('outhide8" + start+ "')\"><div class=\"delete_box_3\"><img src=\"images/delete_icon.png\" alt=\"\"></div></a><div class=\"list_box_3\"><div class=\"box_message\">2</div><img src=\"images/box_icon2.png\" alt=\"\"></div><div class=\"list_box_4\"><div class=\"box_message\">1</div><img src=\"images/box_icon3.png\" alt=\"\"></div><div class=\"list_box_5\"><img src=\"images/box_icon4.png\" alt=\"\"></div></div></div></div></div></div>";
        var star=document.getElementById('star8'+ start).value;

        }




        answers = answers + 1;
        start++;

    }




});

      });//]]>  





       var start=1;
    function poppy()
     {
write = document.getElementById('popupcont');
    write.innerHTML = write.innerHTML + "<div id=\"answer"+ start+"\"><div class=\"pop_inn\" id=\"outhide"+ start+"\"><h3>Activity</h3><div><p>Test.</p><button class=\"md-close button\" onClick=\"hideblocks('outhide" + start+ "')\">Close me!</button></div></div></div>";
   answers = answers + 1;
    start++;
     }



var answers = 0;
function addAnswer()
{
write = document.getElementById('buttons');
write.innerHTML = write.innerHTML + "<input type=\"text\" id=\"\" <br>";
answers = answers + 1;
}


      $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#buttons").sortable({
            stop: function (event, div) {
                var order = $("#buttons").sortable('toArray').toString();
                console.log(order);
            }
        });
    });


    //<![CDATA[ 

      $(function(){

$('#buttons2').sortable({});

    })
       //]]>  


       //pop-overlay

         $(document).ready(function() {
        /*
         *  Simple image gallery. Uses default settings
         */

        $('.fancybox').fancybox();

        /*
         *  Different effects
         */

    });
         //editable_text
```

When I drag and drop a file into content if I add some text and then another file drag and drop then previous file's all data changes to default.

Comment: are you using jquery-ui by any chance?

Comment: yes m using jquery-ui.js filke

Comment: is there can array work to store first file's edited data and if i drag new file then other file info not changed